# 3D-Plot with an inequality condition for parameter values

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to `ListPlot3D` the following function

$f=\frac{-\frac{(t-1) (d-s) \left(2 c d (d (q-1)+s)-s \left(-2 d^2+d (s+2)+s^2\right)\right)}{2 s^2}+d^2-d s-d t+s t}{s}$

against $c \in [0,1]$ and $q \in [1,2]$ under the conditions of $s=2$, $d=0.8$, $t=0$, $0\leq c \leq 1$, and $1 \leq q \leq \frac{1}{c}$.

I'm struggling with how to reflect the last condition, i.e. $1 \leq q \leq \frac{1}{c}$ in my Mathematica code. I used `Assumption` but didn't work.

Here is the code I tried:

```
Block[{s = 2, d = 0.8, t = 0}, f = (d^2 - d s - ((d - s) (2 c d (d (-1 + q) + s) - s (-2 d^2 + s^2 + d (2 + s))) (-1 + t))/(2 s^2) - d t + s t)/s; maxn = Flatten[Table[{c, q, f}, {c, 0, 1, .1}, {q, 1, 2, .1}, Assumptions -> {0 < c <= 1, 1 <= q <= 1/c}], 1];] {ListPlot3D[maxn, AxesLabel -> {"c", "q", "V"}]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of sampling the function yourself, you can use `Plot3D`.

```
expr = Block[{s = 2, d = 0.8, t = 0}, 
  (d^2 - d s - ((d - s) (2 c d (d (-1 + q) + s) - 
          s (-2 d^2 + s^2 + d (2 + s))) (-1 + t))/(2 s^2) - d t + s t)/s
];

Plot3D[expr, {c, 0, 1}, {q, 1, 2},
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{c, q}, 1 <= q <= 1/(c + $MinMachineNumber)]
]
```

[image]

As you can see, the troubling condition can be incorporated by using `RegionFunction`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way: Iterators may depend on iterators that precede them.

```
expr = Block[{s = 2, d = 0.8, t = 0},
 (d^2 - d s - ((d - s) (2 c d (d (-1 + q) + s) - 
     s (-2 d^2 + s^2 + d (2 + s))) (-1 + t))/(2 s^2) - d t + s t)/s];

Plot3D[expr, {c, 0, 1}, {q, 1, Min[2, 1/(c + $MinMachineNumber)]}]
```

[image]

This also works, if you don't like fudging with `$MinMachineNumber` (which doesn't affect the plot at all):

```
q2[c_?NumericQ] := Min[2, Quiet@Check[1/c, Infinity]];
Plot3D[expr, {c, 0, 1}, {q, 1, q2[c]}]
```

Alternatively, you can special-case zero (the definition for `c == 0` must come first):

```
ClearAll[q2];
q2[0 | 0.] := 2;
q2[c_?NumericQ] := Min[2, 1/c];
```

Comment: I should point out that when the boundary can be specified in this way, a crisp, clean boundary can be computed with much less computational effort than the sampling/interpolation method used in `RegionFunction`.

Answer (score 2):

Some of your `c` are zero and Mathematica complains about testing for `1/c`

So I assume any result 1<=q<=1/0 is acceptable by checking for c==0 first and only if c !=0 do I also check for 1/c

```
maxn = Flatten[Table[{c, q, f}, {c, 0, 1, .1}, {q, 1, 2, .1}],1];
newmaxn=Select[maxn,(1<=#[[2]]&&#[[1]]==0)||1<=#[[2]]<=1/#[[1]]&];
ListPlot3D[newmaxn]
```